# Изучение С/С++

Tags: c++, c, книги

Начал изучать С и С++. Это мой первый опыт в данной сфере (пока еще не знаю ни одного языка программирования). Какие книги посоветуете почитать? С каких примеров лучше начать? Чего лучше не делать?

Comment: Я думаю вам все таки для начала нужно определится, что вы будете изучать С или все таки С++.

Comment: Новичек-нулевичек? Отложите "С" в сторонку, начните с этого:
"**Песни о Паскале**" - программирование для школьников и начинающих.
Скачивать здесь:
http://oleg-derevenets.narod.ru


Comment: Я думаю вам всё таки не стоит брать C как первый язык. Посмотрите что-нибудь попроще.

Comment: @Oleg_D, мне кажется, что нужно быть чуть-чуть повежливее. За это Вам минус. Все когда-то были начинающими. А начинать можно и с Си/Си++. Если человек действительно хочет научиться программировать, то он своего добьется. Пускай в случае с Си/Си++ это будет сложнее сделать и то, только поначалу.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky просто  мне интересно. Человек с такой репутацией, четыре года тому назад, задавал такой вопрос. Как все-таки вы нашли решение? Где черпали знания?

Comment: Ничего себе когда вопрос задан

Answer (score 11):

1. Советую Вам выбрать для начала что-то одно - либо Си, либо C++. Все-таки стиль написания программ для них несколько отличается, даже если не учитывать, что C++ - объектно-ориентированный.
2. От себя порекомендую C++. Лучшая книга для изучения C++ - Страуструп Б. "Язык программирования С++", как Вам тут уже написали.
3. Еще могу посоветовать очень хорошую книгу о программировании вообще - Макконнелл С. "Совершенный код". Это не о каком-то конкретном языке, а о принципах написания хороших программ.
   Успехов

Comment: человек, который не знает ни одного языка программирования, не сможет эффективно учиться по Страуструпу. Я даже когда имел опыт около года, некоторые вещи не понимал по этой книге (при том что был далеко не самым тупым на курсах вроде). 
Вы приводите список хороших книг, но для старта это явно не то

Comment: Дополню - начните с си, потом изучайте с++.

Comment: @Jetu, а ведь автор вопроса последний раз посещал форум 20 Янв 11 года в 0:57.

Похоже, что он уже изучил и Си и С++.

Comment: @avp ахаххахах вот я лох )) не посмотрел на дату )))

Answer (score 8):

- Керниган Б., Ритчи Д. Язык программирования Си
- Страуструп Б. Язык программирования С++
- Дейтел Х., Дейтел П. Как программировать на C++

Answer (score 7):

1. Герберт Шилдт "Полный справочник по С/С++"
2. Скотт Мэйерс "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ"

Comment: самые полезные книги, но только не для новичков...

Answer (score 6):

Б. Керниган, Д. Ритчи "Язык программирования Си".
Можно еще книгу Бруно Бабе "Просто и ясно о Borland C++".
Если интересно станет, можно графику по книгам Л. Аммерала поделать;)

Answer (score 6):

Стивен Прата "Язык программирования С++. лекции и упражнения" -- тоже неплохая книга для начинающих. Страуструпа уже потомнадо читать, когда основы языка будут усвоены. начинать с "талмуда" Бъёрна очень сложно.

Answer (score 5):

Народ! Какой Страуструп? Он же только начинает изучать. Эта книга совершенно ему не нужна на этом этапе. Тебе нужна книга: ***Джесс Либерти "Освой самостоятельно С++ за 21 день", пятое издание***. В ней доступно объясняется как раз для начинающих. 
+ можешь скачать с нета видеоуроки. но тут уж погугли )) материала много ))

Comment: Я не верю в книжки типа "освой XXX за неделю". Я программирую на C++ уже который год. И уже понял, что нифига я его не знаю. Это слишком многогранный язык.
Нужно начинать с С. Он существенно проще и перейти к синтаксису С++ будет проще. Главное акцентировать внимание на отличиях, чтобы не образовалась каша в голове. 
И обязательно - научиться пользоваться справкой как используемой среды, так и вещами типа MSDN. Это очень спасает.

Comment: согласен что со Страуструпа лучше не начинать. его следует прочесть, но он вряд ли хорош как первая книга по с++ (по крайней мере если у вас почти нет опыта программирования перед этим).
что-то типа "С++ для чайников" или "за 21 день" - вполне нормально для быстрого старта. А потом углублять знания.
Идея начинать с Си тоже кажется странной, совсем это ни к чему..

Answer (score 5):

По С лучше Гукин, Дэн. С для "чайников",  2-е издание. Глубин нет, зато все понятно, а С++ Шилд, С++ базовый курс. Третье издание.

Comment: Минус за Шилдта.

Answer (score 5):

По С++ так же можно посоветовать Р. Лафоре "Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++"

Answer (score 5):

Много есть хороших книг по С++. Сам я начинал учить С++ по книге Дейтела "Как программировать на С++". Книга неплохая, но все же есть лучше. Жаль только, что об этом я узнать уже, когда Дейтела прочитал на половину. Новичку в самый раз будет учебник Стивена [Прата](http://iguania.ru/knigi-po-programmirovaniiu/s-prata-yazik-programmirovaniya-s--lektsii-i-uprazhneniya.html) "Язык программирования С++. Лекции и упражнения". Доступно написано и практически все понятно)

Answer (score 4):

Господи зачем для изучения рекомендовать Страуструпа??? Это полнейший идиотизм! Тот кто такое советует сам не знает языка, а где то услышал про Страуструпа! У Страутрупа стиль прогамирования очень сильно отличается от реальности, в которую попадает человек после изученя  языка. Вы хотите у человека отбить сразу всё желание писать на си++?  Срауструп очень котегоричен в своей книге, он просто отрицает все другие стили програмирования кроме его. Его стоит читать для изучения стиля, а не для изучения языка! Мало того, если человек не знает ни одного языка нормально, не умеет программировать вообще, то ни в коем случае не стоит читать Страуструпа, он его просто не поймёт.    Страуструп - взрыв мозга для новичка!

В реале лучше всего учится по Шилдту, а Си по Риччи и Кернигану!

Comment: книга Шилдта Основы С++ слишком тяжелый, явно не на новичков расчитан

Comment: +1, Страуструп для новичка - бред. Это может быть по-настоящему интересно уже для достаточно опытных программистов. По Страуструпу разве что есть смысл начать изучать STL

Comment: "У Страутрупа стиль прогамирования очень сильно отличается от реальности, в которую попадает человек после изученя языка" - вот это больше похоже на бред, а в изучении по Страуструпу есть какой-то смысл. Он создал язык, и в своей книге описал, как язык использовать. Как раз это и надо читать, если необходимость изучения C++ есть осмысленный выбор. Учиться программировать вообще и изучать, что такое ООП, не есть изучать C++.

Answer (score 3):

Начни с Си хватит книжки Д. Ритчи, Б. Кернигана, а там посмотришь надо тебе больше или нет)

Answer (score 2):

**Б. Страуструп. "Принципы и практика использования C++"**

Как раз для начинающих.

А те кто боится читать его книгу "Язык программирования С++" никогда не станет программистом C++, поскольку это Библия программиста на С++. Любой начинающий программист должен начинать использовать эту книгу. Не читать а именно использовать, т.е. читать отдельные главы и учить отдельные темы с которыми он в данный момент своей жизни сталкивается, поскольку ни в одной другой книге не будет написано более точно (кроме разумеется Стандарта).

Answer (score 1):

Отличные книги Архангельского А.Я

Answer (score 1):

Ну я тоже начинающий я пользуюсь книгами

- Д.А. Клюшин "Полный курс С++"
- В.В. Тимофеев "C++ как он есть(самоучитель)"

Вроде не сложно, получается, бывает думать надо.

Answer (score 1):

Крупник А. изучаем C++ **лучший учебник** я сейчас учу С++ - попробовал много учебников, но этот-лучший